# Acer Aspire One -- strange battery problem, charges only up to ~90%

Tags: battery, battery-life, acer-aspire-one

I have this strange problem on the acer aspire one d250. It happened already once before, stayed for about two weeks, and then "fixed itself".

The problem is as follows:
the battery can't seem to get fully charged; ie the indicator is stuck at about 90% (it's probably not a software problem -- I have ArchLinux and Windows 7 installed and both report exactly the same) and it never passes that value, but it still shows the status as "charging" (I tried everything I could think of -- leaving it charging for extremely long amounts of time, doing a few complete charge-recharge cycles, removing/reinserting the battery, cleaning the connectors, even updating the BIOS, etc., and nothing helped).

Also, when it is getting charged, it charges pretty fast until about 70% and then progresses extremely slowly.

The battery holds the charge that appears on the battery indicator normally. Just can't get the battery to charge fully -- I can't get it past the 90%.

At first I thought this would be a simple battery failure (even if the computer is not that old, about 6-7 months), but as I mentioned it happened once before, and then one day it fixed itself.

I tried contacting Acer about this, but the support was not helpful, completely stupid, it seemed like they used canned responses, the usual.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: I would try running a diagnostic program to report the raw data (present capacity, max capacity, charge rate etc.) from the battery. I believe you can get this information using the trial version of AIDA64 (http://www.aida64.com/downloads). There may be freeware programs that do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This may be by design.  If you rarely use your laptop off the adapter, the computer may be detecting this and avoiding full charge to increase the lifetime of the battery.  A Li-Ion battery looses capacity faster when fully charged.

Comment: +1.  Not familiar with the Acer model, but I just finished setting up a Samsung which had a similar feature you could enable in the BIOS.  The feature limits the maximum battery charge to 80% to extend the life of the lithium polymer battery.

Answer (score 0):

IS there a battery calibration cycle on BIOS??
may you need to calibration your battery. The so-called calibration is that when the battery's actual capacity and the control circuit is not the same as the record of capacity, do an operation of fully charging and discharging battery. So the control circuit record, bringing them closer to the actual situation of the battery.

there are some infermation may help you

Comment: As for the BIOS, I've checked, there isn't anything like that, it's quite limited in general. I've done full cycles of complete discharge and complete recharge about 4 times already and the situation is still the same..